# getElementsByClassName() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The follwing code is to sort form list options alphabetically but the 'getElementsByClassName()' is not working and I cant figure out why.

I am using the latest jQuery.

```
window.onload=function(){
    function sortlist() {
        var cl = document.getElementsByClassName('car_options');
        var clTexts = new Array();

        for(i = 1; i < cl.length; i++) {
            clTexts[i-1] =
                cl.options[i].text.toUpperCase() + "," +
                cl.options[i].text + "," +
                cl.options[i].value;
    }   
    clTexts.sort();

    for(i = 1; i < cl.length; i++) {
        var parts = clTexts[i-1].split(',');
        cl.options[i].text = parts[1];
        cl.options[i].value = parts[2];
    }
    sortlist();
}
```

in body section

```
     <form action="" method="get">

        <p><label for="car_make"></label>
          <select id="car_make"  class="car_options" name="car_make"> 

            <option value="">By Make</option>
            <option value="Vauxhall">Vauxhall</option>
            <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
            <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option>
            <option value="Lexus">Lexus</option>
            <option value="Audi">Audi</option>
            <option value="Ford">Ford</option>

                </select>


          <label for="car_color"></label>

          <select name="car_color" id="car_color" class="car_options">
                  <option value="">By Color</option>

            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Black">Black</option>
            <option value="Grey">Grey</option>


          </select>


          <input type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="Search">
         </form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `document.getElementsByClassName('car_options')[0]`

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a set of elements which have all the given class names.

If you have multiple elements then we have to iterate it through. like

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('car_options');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

    }, false);
}
```

Note: In IE it is supported on **IE9+**

### EDIT

Updated Code

```
function sortlist() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('car_options');
    for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
        var cl = elements[j];
        var clTexts = new Array();

        for (i = 1; i < cl.options.length; i++) {
            clTexts[i - 1] = cl.options[i].text.toUpperCase() + "," + cl.options[i].text + "," + cl.options[i].value;
        }
        clTexts.sort();

        for (i = 1; i < cl.options.length; i++) {
            var parts = clTexts[i - 1].split(',');
            cl.options[i].text = parts[1];
            cl.options[i].value = parts[2];
        }
    }
}
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tUzsd/)

Comment: so what should i replace addeventlistner with ??

Comment: Always cache the length especially when iterating through live collection. Checking length everytime is expensive.

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is wrong.

You are iterating over cl(which is the collection of all select lists).

Then accessing options of each list by the same index. Your code produces array out of bounds exception

Comment: What are you trying to achieve